# XSD to define .NET enum (Name and Value)

Tags: .net, enums, xsd

I'm looking for a way to express an enum definition by means of XSD. 
As you know, in .NET you can define an enum by listing the individual aliases but you can also assign a value to any alias name:

```
enum DataLevel
{
  Aarea = 1,
  Outlet = 2
}
```

The only way I know to represent an enumeration in XSD allows specifying the names but not the assigned value:

```
<xs:simpleType name="DataLevel">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Area"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Outlet"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Can you help me to express the given enumeration so the alias names and te valies are represented by the XSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with XML Schema (XSD). It does not have the concept of an enumeration in the .NET sense.